# Create trigger on create role

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a PostgreSQL database. I create new *READ-ONLY* users as follows:

```
$ sudo -upostgres psql postgres
postgres=# CREATE ROLE readonly;
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
postgres=# BEGIN;
postgres=# CREATE ROLE "<PUT_READONLY_USERNAME_HERE>" WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<USE_A_NICE_STRONG_PASSWORD_PLEASE' IN ROLE readonly;
postgres=# COMMIT;
```

Also I have a table "is_admin" where I manually add new users (it happens really rarely). If it is read-only user `users.is_admin = false` and if it is user with all priveleges `users.is_admin = tru`e.

```
   users.oid     users.is_admin (bool)
       1            true
       2            false
       3            false
      ...            ...
```

Then in code I check if user is admin or not with this query:

```
SELECT users.is_admin
FROM users.users
JOIN pg_authid ON pg_authid.oid = users.oid::oid
WHERE rolname = "PUT_ROLNAME";
```

So, the main question is how to automatically add new users to "is_admin" table? I read that trigger or smth like that can help me (for example,  trigger ON CREATE ROLE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create triggers on administrative change, like `create role`.

But I think you don't need `is_admin` column at all. You can simply use

```
select pg_has_role('username', 'rolename', 'MEMBER');
```

to determine if user has some role or not.